# CSV-file with many tables

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

The csv file contains more than one table, it might look like this:

> ```
> "Vertical Table 1"
> ,
> "id","visits","downloads"
>  1, 4324, 23
>  2, 664, 42
>  3, 73, 44
>  4, 914, 8
>
> "Vertical Table 2"
> ,
> "id_of_2nd_tab","visits_of_2nd_tab","downloads_of_2nd_tab"
>  1, 524, 3
>  2, 564, 52
>  3, 63, 84
>  4, 814, 8
> ```

To read one table I use "*HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy*" from [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)
which allows me to map the csv-table entries into a List of *TableDataBean* objects, as seen below:

```
HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<TableDataBean> strat = new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<TableDataBean>();

CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(path), ',');
strat.setType(TableDataBean.class);
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("Number of visits", "visits");
map.put("id", "id");
map.put("Number of downloads", "downloads");
strat.setColumnMapping(map);
CsvToBean<TableDataBean> csv = new CsvToBean<TableDataBean>();
List<TableDataBean> list = csv.parse(strat, reader);
```

This works fine for the first table, but when it cames to the second, the values and the **attributes** are mapped to the same attribute of the first table. The output for

```
for(TableDataBean bean : list){System.out.println(bean.getVisits());}
```

would look like this:

> ```
>  4324
>  664
>  73
>  914
>  null
>  null
>  null
>  visits_of_2nd_tab
>  524
>  564
>  63
>  814
> ```

I don't wanna split the file into many files containing each of them one table.
So what do you suggest ? Is there any other Library that supports this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it! I thought that the type of *reader* have to be of *CSVReader*. It actually turned out that I can feed the methode *parse* with any object inheriting from the *Reader* class.

Now I can read the entire csv-file into a String, splitt it, pack each of the new Strings into a *StringReader* and than pass it to the *parse* methode.